# How do you count the number of links in a chain?

Tags: maintenance, chain

I thought this was a simple question but apparently there is some confusion - and it's good to have a basic question to refer people to.

**How many "links" are in these short bits of chain:**

Image A (the original image for this question):

[image]

---

Image B:

Some people thought the bit of chain was too short and was missing a set of rollers, or wasn't in a loop. Here's a longer length of chain -- exactly twice as long as Image A, in fact.

[image]

In your responses, try to make it clear whether you're referring to Image A or Image B.

Comment: A quick way to count the number of links if you can remove the chain is to measure the chain with a measuring tape. Each link of the chain will be 1/2 an inch long. Take the total length of the chain in inches and multiply by 2 to get the number of links.  If your chain is 57.5 inches long, you have 115 links. Measure from the middle of the first pin, to the middle of the last pin.

Comment: The question of how *I* count links is almost irrelevant, there's an industry standard way. So the question becomes "do I count links the right way".

Comment: @Mσᶎ  what is the industry standard? I believe it would be to say that the above is a four link chain, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at any of the [chain manufacturer pages](https://www.sram.com/sram/mountain/products/pc-x1-chain) they say "114 links" or whatever, and it's unlikely they're selling chain in 114 x 2.5cm = more than 2m chunks. If you think about it in terms of chain pitch it might be easier - most bikes use 1/2" pitch, Shitmano for a while sold 10mm pitch, and in both cases they're talking about the gap between pins (or teeth on the matching sprockets).

Comment: @RoboKaren If you want to clear up how the industry counts a chain a picture with a connector would eliminated confusion.  That chain is missing a roller and a pin so people cannot readily envision how it becomes a working loop.

Comment: This is a tougher question to ask and to answer than I thought it'd be!!!!

Comment: I usually count them 1,2,3...  .

Comment: @David - but what are you counting? BentSpoke's answer and comments indicate that St. Sheldon Brown thought that a "complete link" was "one inner and one outer half-link"

Comment: F.Y.I. motorcycle chains count each pin as a link so for example a standard chain length for a motorcycle (street bike) is 120 links (5/8" pitch typically) and then it can be shortened to some even length such as 118, 116, 114....  The easy answer to this question is the # of links of the chain can be determined by counting each pin.  Therefore a 120 link bike chain (with 1/2" pitch) will be 60" (which is 5 feet) long.

Comment: Thanks @David - I used your example to clarify my answer.

Comment: On my motorcycle, I just used the master link as a reference point then just spun the rear tire so I could count up the links.  I imagine a similar thing can be done with a bicycle.  You could even mark one pin with a sharpie marker for easy reference.  Oh and RoboKaren, if my answer helped you, why no upvote on it?

Comment: I suspect the Law Of Bigger Numbers applied to sales means that chains that could be called 61 "full links" (an inner and outer pair) will be described  as "112 links" purely because your packaging has "twice as many" even though each link is half as long.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each set of "inner plates" is a link. Each set of "outer plates" is a "link."

In the photo below  you can see two whole links.

[image]

Thus to answer the question, Image A in the question above has 4 links. Image B has 8 links.

When you buy this box of chain that is labeled as having "120 links" and is standard 1/2" pitch, you should expect to get 60 inner links, 60 outer links, for a total of 120 links and it should measure 60" long:

[image: Sram PC1071 - 120 Links]

Another way of thinking about links is that a "link" as a "place where a tooth goes" - thus if a chain wrapped completely around a 44 tooth chainring - it would have 44 links --  with 22 outer-plate-links and 22 inner-plate-links.

---

Another way to analogize is with a standard chain:

[image]

Everyone would agree that the standard chain image above has six links - each link creating one "hole".

---

<sub>Please note that there is a small but vocal group of people (including Sheldon Brown) who count a ["complete link" as "one inner and one outer half-link"](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html). Counting "complete" links has the effect of halving the number of links (thus Image A would have 2 complete links, Image B would have 4 complete links, and that five foot length of SRAM chain would have 60 complete links).</sub>
<sub>Counting "complete" and "half" links as Sheldon does is non-standard at least as far as the industry is concerned. If someone starts talking about "complete" and "half" links when talking about chain length, you should clarify with them what they are talking about as you may end up with half or double the number of links you might otherwise expect.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35834/discussion-on-answer-by-robokaren-how-do-you-count-the-number-of-links-in-a-chai); additional comments no longer relevant to the edited post have also been deleted.

Answer (score 6):

But is is not as easy as counting links on an open chain.

The links must connect.  With inner and outer you must have an equal number of inner and outer. The total must be even.

Let's say one link was removed from that chain.  You would have to remove another to make it two links to connect and at two folded back on itself and I am not sure you could even call it a two link chain.

And then there is the connector thing.  Connector is typically outer so you want the raw chain to end on inner both ends and you need to add one for the connector.  Some times on a new chain the connector is on the chain and some times it is packaged separately.  You have pin type one time connectors and reusable connector links.

You can use a 1/2 link connector to get an odd number of links.  1/2 link is used by the wider SS and fixie where you may need a more exact length.  I don't think it is used in the narrow chains designed for derailleur.
[image: 1/2 link]

[image] HL is also a style of chain but it is pretty much limited to SS, fixie, and BMX as far as I know.

Below is a SRAM with a reusable PowerLock on the left.  The picture is 14 links.  This chain is packaged as 114 links.  You will typically cut the chain down and save the spare links for repair.  Rather than count I just lay the old chain down next to the new.  There is going to be some stretch so you may need to adjust to match up links (or pins/rollers). 
[image]

It is not like you go the shop and buy a specific size so I have never found a need to know the number of lengths in my chain. 114 and 116 seem to be common packaging. If you have a touring with a long chain stay or tandem then you would have some custom length chains. I suspect they just buy multiple packages and some extra connectors. You can buy spools of raw chain.

Every manufacturer seems to count chain length the same in chain packages. 
Here is a safe definition if you want to remove the possible confusion of plate, half, or full.

## On the connected (or a configuration that will connect) chain count the number of rollers

Comment: Not really important for most of us, but its worth noting with the new Wide/Narrow chainrings a 1/2 link cannot be used.

Comment: @mattnz That would really mess with the narrow wide harmony

Comment: This does not answer the question of how many links there are in Image A (the original image) -- or amended, Image B.

Comment: @RoboKaren So, is this a poll?  First, is not even a valid chain.

Comment: A chain does not have to be in a loop to be a chain. Most of the time, when we buy a chain, it isn't in a loop but is broken.  Second, not sure why you think this is a poll. Your comment spurred me to add a clarifying image.

Comment: @RoboKaren You asking for "a number" well two number now - that is a poll.  So, it is not in a loop - still not a valid chain and I don't think assigning a number is of value.  I am aware a chain is not sold in a loop and I think my answer covers that clearly (with a number).

Comment: I do not think the word "poll" means what you think it means. I am asking how the right way to count links is and gave two examples. For image A, you could have said "2 complete links and 2 incomplete links" if you wish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35845/discussion-between-frisbee-and-robokaren).

Comment: When you have an odd bike, like a recumbent or a tandem, you may need to buy a chain where you have to ask for the number of links you need, having counted yourself.

Comment: @Willeke See my answer "If you have a touring with a long chain stay or tandem then you would have some custom length chains"

Answer (score 3):

I didn't really see this point of view yet, so I'll add it.

The key here is in the word itself. A *link* is **not** the flat bit of metal with two holes for pins, it is the "link" *between* two of these pieces. In other words, a 120 link chain has 120 connections between bits of metal. Counting the pins works, as does counting the holes between pins. This means that the open chain in image A in the question only has three links, while the closed chain in image B has eight.

However, general parlance does not always follow this. If you take a single loop from a typical chain, you might call that a "chain link", even though there is no actual "link". So this might be a bit of etymology more than anything else.

Comment: Uh, count the number of rollers is link in  bold print in my answer

Comment: And what is a roller supposed to be? Sounds like some sort of wheel to me, but chains have no wheels. Do you mean pin?

Comment: Uh, roller chain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain  If those round contact points did not roll it would be very inefficient and things would wear out rapidly.

Comment: I get that now, but you're missing the point of my answer, which has to do with the actual meaning of the work *link*.

Comment: And you are missing my point.  A roller also removers the possible confusion of the word link from the count.   You stated you had not seen the point of view yet.

Comment: My POV *wasn't* stated, because you said 'count the pins', while I said that, 'a link is the connection between two plates, not the plates themselves'. I even said at the end of my answer that "this might be a bit of etymology more than anything else". I'm not an expert on bicycles, but I consider myself fairly knowledgeable with the english language and how examining the etymology of a word or phrase can make things clearer.

Comment: Roller is a word and it is part of the chain (even though you asserted not).   It it that bits of metal.  You asserted that point of view hand not been presented and I pointed that it was in my answer in bold.

Comment: I never said "roller" was not a word, nor asserted any such thing.There's no point resaying what I've already said, so I'll just say that extended discussions don't belong in comments.

Comment: "but chains have no wheels"

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of pins/rollers that would be present if you closed the chain, in this case Image A would be classified as having  four "links" - answer (c), but really (e) because I don't think description quite matches the counting procedure. *This is why I always hated multiple choice!!!*

By the way - I am not clear on what you imply counting inner and outer "links" - inner and outer plates are involved in each junction/link.

Comment: Sorry, fixed my question, I meant plates not links. Thx.

Comment: @RoboKaren - I am still not clear on your description, there are 4 inner and 4 outer plates in the example.  "Count both the number of inner and outer plates" would give you 8!

Comment: Ah, that was what I was trying to avoid - both tautology and confusion. Maybe "set of plates" would be clearer?

Comment: Got rid of multiple choice. :-)

Comment: Getting there @RoboKaren but not any clearer for me, set of plates could still be mis-interpreted because you don't get an inner plate without a corresponding outer plate in a 'regular' chain that's complete

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps there is some confusion in the term "link." Here are a couple of definitions that seem to be in use:

1. A place where two things connect
2. An independent section of chain
3. The smallest section of chain that can be removed or added to an existing chain and the chain could still be rejoined.

Under the both the first and second definitions, chain A in your example has four links and chain B has eight links.

The venerable Sheldon Brown seems to subscribe to the third definition. [He refers](http://sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html#chain) to a single set of inner or outer plates as a *half link*. A set of inner *and* outer plates constitutes a *full link*. This is because (barring non-standard equipment like half link connectors) it is impossible to join two ends of the chain if they both consist of inner or outer plates. You *must* have inner plates on one end and outer plates on the other. By this definition, chain A in your image has two full links or four half links and chain B has four full links and eight half links.

Personally, I prefer the third definition because it is the smallest functional piece of chain.