# What size chain do i use if I've changed the front sprocket

Tags: bike-fit

I am converting a 7 speed Kent Bayside beach cruiser in to motorized bicycle. I had to change the front Sprocket from a 40 tooth to a 44 tooth, due to the need for wide crank setup. Now the chain does not catch all the teeth and continually slips off the sprocket... How do I determine what the right chain is for this bike???

Comment: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing

Comment: You added four teeth, so you need enough chain to cover four teeth. That's two links or four, depending how you count.

Comment: @Móż - Bleh. There's a right way to [count links](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/37191/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-links-in-a-chain).

Comment: Can you expand on "the need for wide crank setup"  ?   If the cranks are further apart, that may have put the whole chainring out of line.

Comment: @Batman yes, and there's a right way to spell colour, but that doesn't stop some people consistently getting it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The chain goes (about) halfway around the front chain ring, so you need enough chain to cover two more teeth, which is two links of chain (one inner, one outer).  In all but the lowest gear (largest gear on the rear) you should be OK already.  It seems strange that you wouldn't catch all the teeth if the chain were too short. It sounds like your chain ring is out of line with the rear and you need a chain guide to keep the chain in line.  That would make more sense if you moved the chain ring outboard from where it was.